# Is there a boolean method that allows you to check the contents within a JLabel?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a mini trade machine, like the one seen on the ESPN website for a class of mine. I want to click a button that adds player info into a label on the "trading block." I need to use an IF-ELSE statement to check whether a label has text already and if it does to place the info into the next label. Is there a boolean method for this like a ".hasText" or something? I've been looking all over but cant find anything. If not does anyone know a better way to do this? I'm working in Java by the way.

Comment: [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))?

Comment: Are you using Java, or Javascript?

Comment: I don't think there is something like that, can't you just use [`getText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#getText()) and check if returned value is null or empty?

Comment: I'm using java and I tried to do getText == null but that didn't work

Comment: @A.PROSCIA what exactly did not work? What is returned by getText()?